# Divide one column into multiple in a new table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table set up like this

```
id (PK) | regID (FK) | fieldID | fieldValue
```

There are multiple fields that can be used to enter data and which are all stored in the fieldValue column.  What I'd like to do is migrate this data over to a 2nd table that looks like

```
regID | Name | Occupation | etc | etc
```

Where the columns (other than regID) are associated with fieldIDs.

I first tried populating the new table with the unique regIDs and then tried to update the rest of the row information from there based on the matching regIDs and appropriate fieldIDs but I wasn't able to get far with that.

Then I tried something like

```
`INSERT INTO newData(regID, pName) VALUES
((SELECT distinct regID FROM fieldData),
 (SELECT fieldValue FROM fieldData WHERE fieldID= 14 ORDER BY regID))`
```

which obviously didn't work.  I'm still thinking that the first option may be the better way, but even then I don't think it's great.  Any ideas how to get this data moved over to be more organized?

Comment: What error did you get on your first try?

Comment: For that 2nd query I'm getting " #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row".The first thing I tried, I can't remember, I can go back and do a rewrite of what I tried if that's the one you were asking about

Comment: So you are intentionally trying to de-normalize that data?  Why?

Comment: This 2nd table I'm trying to populate is basically just for ease of use.  I can find all the data I need, but if I want to export values to a CSV or something to send to someone else to use for another task it's much easier to read `John Smith | Sales | Ohio | etc` as opposed to all that data in 1 column, especially with there being many duplicate entries of the fieldValues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `case based aggregation`

Here is how you do it using `insert into select` and `case based aggregation`

```
INSERT INTO newData(regID, pName, occupation) 
select  regID,
        max(case when filedid=14 then fieldDate end) as pName,
        max(case when filedid=15 then fieldDate end) as occupation,
        .....
from fieldData
group by regID
```

Comment: oh ok that makes sense, but I'm not sure what the purpose of the max() around the cases is for?  I'll give it a go when I have a few minutes.

Comment: @jrut127, for a given regId, you will have multiple columns in fieldData, but you need only one value per filedId so doing group by regId and then max value. this is bascially called pivoting the data.